# Windows Update Displays "Downloading Windows 10" instead of Updates

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update

I'm using windows 7 pro and do not want to upgrade to windows 10. To prevent the permanent notifications i've removed update KB3035583. Also the reservation of the upgrade is canceled so Windows Update should not download 10.

But when to execute Windows Update to perform updates it looks like it will download windows 10 but instead it downloads the updates.

It looks that there is some UI issue

Comment: Have you run Disk Cleanup / deleted the **$Windows.~BT** and **$Windows.~WS** folders.

Comment: yes, the **$Windows*** are not existing and the files are cleanup

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of the Windows Update while it's downloading? Don't worry about the rep, just post the link and we can embed it.

Comment: it's the default ["windows 10 is downloading"](http://media2.giga.de/2015/07/Windows-10-wird-heruntergeladen-systemsteuerung.jpg) (image from google)

Comment: [Cancel W10 upgrade after it has downloaded](http://superuser.com/questions/955444/i-cancelled-microsoft-10-reservation-and-uninstalled-kb3035583-but-window-10-is)

Comment: The issue is why does it download instead of the updates, when it is not selected for download.

Answer (score 0):

To Update Windows itself (like security updates, etc.), but not download Windows 10, you can go into Windows Update and select which updates to get. So, you just need to uncheck the Windows 10 download in Windows Update. Now, to be completely sure that the files will not be downloaded in the background, you can further disable updates from automatically downloading (but I think if you uncheck Windows 10 once, it won't automatically download in the future).

Comment: if it was that easy I would not create a question here. Windows 10 is neither selected in any option nor the KB3035583 is installed. But the Windows 7 update downloads Windows 10 instead of regular updates

Comment: I selected everything except windows 10. Click update, and windows 10 is now downloading, not the updates.