# How to prevent hidden windows 10 upgrade?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, upgrade, windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

Recently as per this [article](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2015/09/microsoft-is-downloading-windows-10-to-pcs-even-if-you-dont-reserve-a-copy/)

> For individuals who have chosen to receive automatic updates through
>   Windows Update, we help upgradable devices get ready for Windows 10 by
>   downloading the files they’ll need if they decide to upgrade.

but Microsoft seems to be downloading hidden update in windows 7 :

according to this [article](http://www.theinquirer.net/inquirer/news/2425381/microsoft-is-downloading-windows-10-to-your-machine-just-in-case) :

> An INQUIRER reader pointed out to us that, despite not having
>   'reserved' a copy of Windows 10, he had found that the ~BT folder,
>   which has been the home of images of the new operating system since
>   before rollout began, had appeared on his system. He had no plans to
>   upgrade and had not put in a reservation request.

As per the above two articles there was hidden update for windows 10 with respective to windows 7 and 8 machines ,whats the effective way to stop this hidden update?

right now i cant disable windows update since i wish to patch my system with latest updates,

i checked the question which was marked as possible [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/955444/i-cancelled-microsoft-10-reservation-and-uninstalled-kb3035583-but-window-10-is) :

> inorder to clarify how it differs it talks about the cancelled update
>   ,but this was latest issue which was araised two days before,i didnt
>   dig much about that and believe both were different ,apart from that
>   it was about after the cancellation of update a

nd this one was about preventing such an update from downloading to my pc 
any suggestions to avoid this update?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I Cancelled Microsoft 10 Reservation and uninstalled KB3035583 but Window 10 is still trying to install](http://superuser.com/questions/955444/i-cancelled-microsoft-10-reservation-and-uninstalled-kb3035583-but-window-10-is). [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/951277/tell-windows-7-to-stop-trying-to-upgrade-to-windows-10) is another related question.  You can block specific updates, this is a required step, if you want to fully stop any attempt to prepare your instillation for Windows 10.

Comment: @Ramhound i checked that question friend,it talks about the cancelled update ,but this was latest issue which was araised two days before,i didnt dig much about that and believe both were different ,apart from that it was about after the cancellation of update and this one was about **preventing such an update from downloading to my pc** kindly correct me if i m wrong :)

Comment: I don't see the difference?  The solution is the same.  This isn't a new question, your basic question is, how do you prevent Windows from preparing your instillation for Windows 10, the existing questions I linked to, explain that process.  There isn't a "hidden" update by the way, that is being incorrectly reported, what controls this is clearly documented.  How you prevent this behavior is also clearly documented.

Comment: This question seems more direct and the question I needed the answer to. I need to prevent the update in advance as my windows 7 is running as a service machine that I rarely log in to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit some values in the registry, use Group Policies or Compueter Configuration as described here:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3080351

The registry way:

> ```
> Subkey: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate DWORD
> value: DisableOSUpgrade = 1
> ```